# Need to save contact's to a phone over BT

Tags: bluetooth

I need the string to save contacts on a phone over Bluetooth.

That's the thing, i'm developing a small gadget to scan BT servers; connect with them; send contact informations, after connection accepted, and disconnect. Esp board!!

I managed to get the code done but I still need help with the string I need to write to the server in order the save the contact!!

Let me remind you: I already can do the connection and write strings to the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

To work with contacts on a phone you need to use Bluetooth PBAP profile. It uses vCard format to represents contact details.